# Some Examples of Riemann Integrable functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Some Examples of Riemann Integrable functions:

1) An integrable function $h : [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ with $h(x) > 0 \ \ \forall x$, but $\frac 1h$ is  not integrable on $[0,1]$.

2) A function $f : [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ that  is  not integrable on $[0,1]$ but such that $|f|$ is integrable on $[0,1]$.

3) An integrable function $f$ on $I \subset \Bbb R$  and a non  integrable function $g$ such that $fg$ is integrable on $I$.

For the second one I think $f(x) = k , x \in [0,1] \cap \Bbb Q$ and $f(x) = -k , x \in [0,1] \cap \Bbb Q^c$ will work. Need examples for the other two.

Comment: A Riemann integrable function is _bounded_, by definition. That takes care of one of them. There's a literally completely and utterly trivial example for another one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $1$,

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x,&x\ne 0\\\\
1,&x=0
\end{cases}$$

is integrable on $[0,1]$.  But $1/f(x)=1/x$ for $x\ne 0$ and $1/f(x)=1$ for $x=0$ is not.

---

For $3$, take

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x,&x\ne 0\\\\
1,&x=0
\end{cases}$$

and

$$g(x)=
\begin{cases}
1/x,&x\ne 0\\\\
1,&x=0
\end{cases}$$

Then, $f(x)g(x)=1$ for all $x$ and is integrable on $[0,1]$.